# # symbol in regular expression php

Tags: php, regex

I've got a problem with '#' symbol in regular expression.
I have a string(URL) and it contains # symbol. How can I check it with a regular expression is it here or not here?

This is the string "293892-my-page-#92.html" and regular expression

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)-([\#a-z0-9-])*.html$ page.php [L]
```

Using this I got '293892-my-page-'

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Doesn't match at all. How did you even get it? https://regex101.com/r/BK7RK3/1

Comment: browser write me that current URL '293892-my-page-' not found

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: code in .htaccess

Comment: Your `.htaccess` doesn't send anything to `page.php`. So it's the `page.php` that generates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content = '<a href="http://exaple.com/293892-my-page-#92.html"></a>';

preg_match("|/([0-9+].+?)\.html|si", $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /293892-my-page-#92.html
    [1] => 293892-my-page-#92
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is `#` symbol in the url. It is enough to use `/#/` `(.*#.*).html` as your regex. For something bit more complex - all urls should be similar to this one - `293892-my-page-#92.html`, we can use:

```
([\d]+-[a-z]+-[a-z]+-#[\d]+.)html
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/BK7RK3/2)

Now back to your original regex `[\#a-z0-9-]`. You don't really need to escape any character inside class - there is no need to use `\`. For example `[+*]` will search for a star or a dot. And we can not use character class if `#` is a mandatory. `[#a-z0-9-]+` will match **any character from the class** repeated one or unlimited times:

```
lorem ipsum
012345
------
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/VRleM6/1)